# Oracle Multiple queries with locked row

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, oracle11g

I'm using ORACLE version 11g.

I would like to execute three queries "at the same time" and take care that if one or more of theses queries fails must return both tables to the previous state. These queries are one select to know if the selected row still being possible the make the action, and one update and one insert to do the action.

In my case I need to make an update on the same locked row (obviously no one else should be able to do the action to the same row) and later and insert on another table, only if the result of the select query confirm that the selected row still having the option to execute the action, so the queries will be like these approximately:

```
//this is the row I want to execute the action

$selectedIdFromTable1 = "1";

$query="SELECT attr1 FROM table1 WHERE attr1 = 'oldValueAttr1' AND id = selectedIdFromTable1";
$stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $attr1, "string");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if($result->num_rows == 1){ //I'm still being able to do the action to the row because the row still having the oldValue
//So here the row must be locked to execute the update and the insert only once. Only one user should execute the update and the insert.

    $query="UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = ? WHERE id == $selectedIdFromTable1";
    $stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, 'newValueAttr1', "string");
    $stmt->execute();

    $query="INSERT INTO table2 (attr2) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, 'newValueAttr2', "string");
    $stmt->execute();

}
//here the lock can release the row for future actions (but not this one, because if any one tries the previous select should not find anymore the selected row)
```

Also I'm using the binding system to send the variables more safety. Not sure If can affect the answer.

I'm quite sure that a transaction with locking row is the answer and if it's the answer, I will really appreciate to receive your help with an example of a transaction with Oracle with an example of this situation.

All of that, will be in a Symfony 3.3 project. Probably is not necessary this last information, but the transaction code must be in the symfony project and not in the oracle database for different reasons.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @OldProgrammer excuse me but could you give me an answer as you did the last time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use symfony you will most likely use the DBAL connection.
Transactions are handled as described in [its documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html)

(To me it seems more a transaction feature than a locking one)

Transactions:

```
$conn->beginTransaction();
try{
    // do stuff
    $conn->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Locking is not handled by DBAL

Comment: In my project I use two databases. One with MySQL where I handle throw the Doctrine ORM and is really nice to know that I can lock with the ORM but... the other database is with Oracle 11g and this database I manage it with the DBAL option of Symfony... (can not be with Entitys srry... I just can use normal queries in Oracle because the company wants like this), so I will need to do it with the oracle language with the DBAL connection.

So your answer could be really helpfull for anyone but for me I guess no...

Comment: @RicardEspinàsLlovet No problem, it's also a DBAL feature, see my updated answer

Comment: so... "Locking is not handled by DBAL" -> if it's not handled by DBAL, I suppose I could handle the locking point by the queries from oracle?

Comment: I don't know locking mecanism in Oracle, sorry